# Sendmail to local domain ignoring MX records (part 2)

Tags: sendmail, localhost, gmail, cname-record

I have the exact problem, like in this post: [Sendmail to local domain ignoring MX records](https://serverfault.com/questions/25068/sendmail-to-local-domain-ignoring-mx-records) . I am also using an email provider like GMail For Your Domain (which stores your mail and manages it). I am sending mail from my server directly, but receiving mail is done via Yandex (email provider). Since the server hosts a forum, I prefer to send mail directly from it because using another mail provider can slow things down. Also, when I send 300.000 email to my subscribers, another email provider will surely block me thinking I am sending spam.

My DNS zone now is:

```
;
; GSMFORUM.RU
;

$TTL 1H

gsmforum.ru. SOA ns1.hc.ru. support.hc.ru. (
               2009122268 ; Serial
               1H         ; Refresh
               30M        ; Retry
               1W         ; Expire
               1H       ) ; Minimum

gsmforum.ru.          NS      ns1.hc.ru.
gsmforum.ru.          NS      ns2.hc.ru.
@                     A       79.174.68.223
*.gsmforum.ru.        CNAME   @
ns1                   A       79.174.68.223
ns2                   A       79.174.68.224
@                     MX      10 mx.yandex.ru.
mail                  CNAME   domain.mail.yandex.net.
yamail-xxxxxxxxx      CNAME   mail.yandex.ru.
```

Server hostname is server.gsmforum.ru. May be this is the cause? Can someone explain the reason of the matter (the rules that make sendmail consider domain to be local)? Can I easily change

```
*.gsmforum.ru.        CNAME   @
```

into

```
*.gsmforum.ru.        A   79.174.68.224
```

to solve this problem?

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/mail/local-host-names
localhost
localhost.localdomain
```

This server hosts gsmforum.ru so I cannot put it into another domain like David Mackintosh suggests. Putting the domain in mailertable doesn't solve the problem either: sendmail -bt still shows the address is local. DontProbeInterfaces is also set to true in the sendmail config.

M4 file follows:

```
divert(-1)dnl
dnl #
dnl # This is the sendmail macro config file for m4. If you make changes to
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, you will need to regenerate the
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file by confirming that the sendmail-cf package is
dnl # installed and then performing a
dnl #
dnl #     make -C /etc/mail
dnl #
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Do not advertize sendmail version.
dnl #
dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl
dnl #
dnl # default logging level is 9, you might want to set it higher to
dnl # debug the configuration
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Uncomment and edit the following line if your outgoing mail needs to
dnl # be sent out through an external mail server:
dnl #
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl
dnl #
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True')
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following allows relaying if the user authenticates, and disallows
dnl # plaintext authentication (PLAIN/LOGIN) on non-TLS links
dnl #
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # PLAIN is the preferred plaintext authentication method and used by
dnl # Mozilla Mail and Evolution, though Outlook Express and other MUAs do
dnl # use LOGIN. Other mechanisms should be used if the connection is not
dnl # guaranteed secure.
dnl # Please remember that saslauthd needs to be running for AUTH. 
dnl #
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Rudimentary information on creating certificates for sendmail TLS:
dnl #     cd /usr/share/ssl/certs; make sendmail.pem
dnl # Complete usage:
dnl #     make -C /usr/share/ssl/certs usage
dnl #
dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl #
dnl # This allows sendmail to use a keyfile that is shared with OpenLDAP's
dnl # slapd, which requires the file to be readble by group ldap
dnl #
dnl define(`confDONT_BLAME_SENDMAIL', `groupreadablekeyfile')dnl
dnl #
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl
dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl
dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following limits the number of processes sendmail can fork to accept 
dnl # incoming messages or process its message queues to 20.) sendmail refuses 
dnl # to accept connections once it has reached its quota of child processes.
dnl #
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Limits the number of new connections per second. This caps the overhead 
dnl # incurred due to forking new sendmail processes. May be useful against 
dnl # DoS attacks or barrages of spam. (As mentioned below, a per-IP address 
dnl # limit would be useful but is not available as an option at this writing.)
dnl #
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The -t option will retry delivery if e.g. the user runs over his quota.
dnl #
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
dnl #
dnl # For using Cyrus-IMAPd as POP3/IMAP server through LMTP delivery uncomment
dnl # the following 2 definitions and activate below in the MAILER section the
dnl # cyrusv2 mailer.
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl
dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to only listen on the IPv4 loopback address
dnl # 127.0.0.1 and not on any other network devices. Remove the loopback
dnl # address restriction to accept email from the internet or intranet.
dnl #
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA,Port=smtp')
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 587 for
dnl # mail from MUAs that authenticate. Roaming users who can't reach their
dnl # preferred sendmail daemon due to port 25 being blocked or redirected find
dnl # this useful.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 465, but
dnl # starting immediately in TLS mode upon connecting. Port 25 or 587 followed
dnl # by STARTTLS is preferred, but roaming clients using Outlook Express can't
dnl # do STARTTLS on ports other than 25. Mozilla Mail can ONLY use STARTTLS
dnl # and doesn't support the deprecated smtps; Evolution <1.1.1 uses smtps
dnl # when SSL is enabled-- STARTTLS support is available in version 1.1.1.
dnl #
dnl # For this to work your OpenSSL certificates must be configured.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen on the IPv6 loopback
dnl # device. Remove the loopback address restriction listen to the network.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl
dnl #
dnl # enable both ipv6 and ipv4 in sendmail:
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')
dnl #
dnl # We strongly recommend not accepting unresolvable domains if you want to
dnl # protect yourself from spam. However, the laptop and users on computers
dnl # that do not have 24x7 DNS do need this.
dnl #
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email.
dnl # 
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following example makes mail from this host and any additional
dnl # specified domains appear to be sent from mydomain.com
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just the headers, but the envelope as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just @mydomainalias.com, but @*.mydomainalias.com as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
FEATURE(`dnsbl',`zen.spamhaus.org',`Rejected - your IP is blacklisted by http://www.spamhaus.org')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I did to disable local delivery. I'll be using the example.com domain.

Requirements:

- example.com A entry pointing to IP address assigned to one of the eth interfaces.
- /etc/hosts defining example.com assigned to the very same IP address as above
- example.com MX records pointing to Google servers (ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM, etc)
- default sendmail installation (mine was on Ubuntu)

Steps:

```
vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

at the end:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `example.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `example.com.')dnl
```

and then:

```
sendmailconfig
service sendmail restart
```

testing:

```
echo -e "To: user@example.com\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v
echo -e "To: user\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v
```

You should see it connecting to the google server and then you should see your mail being delivered to your Google inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anoyone come across this problem.

First of all, thanks to sporker and Pawel you put me in the right direction to get this fixed.

My original problem was that sendmail was considering my domain example.com email accounts as local accounts.

These links proved very useful:
[Sendmail to local domain ignoring MX records (part 2)](https://serverfault.com/questions/102647/sendmail-to-local-domain-ignoring-mx-records-part-2)
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2004-September/057382.html
http://objectmix.com/sendmail/367920-sendmail-ignores-mailertable-some-semilocal-domains.html

But in my case, using FreeBSD 8.2, what really did the trick was:

`# cd /etc/mail`

`# vim freebsd.mc`

Add these two lines:

`define(`MAIL_HUB', `example.com.')dnl`

`define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `example.com.')dnl`

Right before:

`MAILER(local)`

`MAILER(smtp)`

`# make`

--- This is output ---

```
 cp freebsd.mc host.example.com.mc
 /usr/bin/m4 -D_CF_DIR_=/usr/share/sendmail/cf/   /usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4 host.example.com.mc > host.example.com.cf
 cp freebsd.submit.mc host.example.com.submit.mc
 /usr/bin/m4 -D_CF_DIR_=/usr/share/sendmail/cf/   /usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4 host.example.com.submit.mc > host.example.com.submit.cf
```

--- End of output ---

`# cp sendmail.cf sendmail.cf.bak`

`# cp host.example.com.cf sendmail.cf`

`# /etc/rc.d/sendmail restart`

Hope this saves some headaches to someone.

Comment: Migrated to PostFix, btw ;)