# Cannot send emails via sendmail and php mail() to certain domains

Tags: email, debian, sendmail, email-server, dsn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outgoing mail from linux not being delivered](https://serverfault.com/questions/344105/outgoing-mail-from-linux-not-being-delivered)

> **SOLUTION**
>   As someone marked this a a duplicate I cannot post the actual answer that worked for me and that can be found here: https://serverfault.com/a/128218/42894 (and not in the duplicate link).

Our website email system based on the CakePHP (1.3) email component has been working perfectly fine for a year and suddently it's not sending emails since yesterday to certain domains anymore, and sometimes even randomly.
I use the `mail()` php function to send emails via the website (account modifications, project updates, ...), and we retrieve our emails via gmail (we are using google apps). When I try to send an email to a user in our own domain, I get the followin error in `/var/log/mail.log`:

> Mar  9 10:12:29 newserverxxxx sm-mta[27999]: q29ACTlt027999: < user@ourdomain.com >... User unknown

We also have issues with `dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred` on certain users from other domains receiving randomly their emails or not.

We are running a Debian (lenny) + sendmail, with everything up to date.

**EDIT:**
here's the `dig mx ourdomain.com` output:

> newserverxxxx:/# dig mx ourdomain.com
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> mx ourdomain.com
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45980
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 7, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 10
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;ourdomain.com.             IN      MX
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      1 aspmx.l.google.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
>   ourdomain.com.      86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>   ourdomain.com.      80089   IN      NS      ns2.phase8.net.
>   ourdomain.com.      80089   IN      NS      ns0.phase8.net.
>   ourdomain.com.      80089   IN      NS      ns1.phase8.net.
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
>   aspmx.l.google.com.     99      IN      A       173.194.67.26
>   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. 97     IN      A       173.194.70.26
>   alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. 99     IN      A       173.194.69.26
>   aspmx2.googlemail.com.  399     IN      A       74.125.43.27
>   aspmx3.googlemail.com.  399     IN      A       74.125.127.27
>   aspmx4.googlemail.com.  536     IN      A       209.85.229.27
>   aspmx5.googlemail.com.  536     IN      A       74.125.157.27
>   ns0.phase8.net.         658     IN      A       85.233.160.69
>   ns1.phase8.net.         658     IN      A       85.233.160.68
>   ns2.phase8.net.         658     IN      A       85.233.164.62
>
> ;; Query time: 7 msec
>   ;; SERVER: 217.112.87.147#53(217.112.87.147)
>   ;; WHEN: Fri Mar  9 11:37:08 2012
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 438

Comment: What does `dig mx ourdomain.com` say? Is it pointing to correct server? Is this server local? Can you send emails to this address from external source?

Comment: `dig` output above. Yes I can; everything's working fine for sending/receiving emails on `ouromain.com`. It's just up to the emails sent from the website.

Comment: is php configured to send mail using an smtp relay, or calls `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` directly? You can test that unknown user message my trying to replicate the session using `telnet`

Comment: No smtp relay used (if would've been simple but google has a very restricted emails quota per hour/day).

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server configured to receive mail for `ourdomain.com` locally, that's why it rejects emails for users who are on the server you forwarding emails to.
Check `/etc/mail/local-host-names` file and remove `ourdomain.com` if it's here.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that frequently appears in SF. This happens because your machine thinks it should deliver mail locally instead of delivering it to Gmail. For a solution to this see for example [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/344189/25640) in a previous similar question at SF.

Comment: As Jason said in his comment, I do not have any of the sections you're talking about; are you sure your code is applicable as it is in `sendmail.mc`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. If you are afraid, backup sendmail.mc and just add them to the bottom of the file. Then see if something breaks. If it does (it won't) copy back the previous sendmail.mc!

Comment: I tried and this is not working, here are several messages from my `mail.log`: `SYSERR(root): buildaddr: no user` || `mailer=relay, pri=34062, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.3.5, stat=Service unavailable` || `DSN: Service unavailable`. I don't know if any of this would help...

Comment: It means that you have not properly and entirely copied the rule to your file. As the "bat book" says _If a triple is missing the address part (the $:), the following error is produced:
554 5.3.5 buildaddr: no user_ (page 697).